# Share target from maps application

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have an application that I want to be a share target for anything that has an address.  I already have the built-in People application working by setting my app manifest to accept `vcf` as a supported file type.

Now I am trying to make it a share target from the Maps application, and for the life of me I can't figure out what to put in the app manifest file to make it work.  I have tried supporting any file type, and adding `Text` and `Windows-8-Preview-Address` as accepted data formats, and still the only app that shows up as a share target in Maps is Messaging.

What the heck kind of data is Maps sharing out?